# Put element data inside element with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

Im trying to put data from one element to another.
I have done an XSL stylesheet thats puts out this two strings.

```
<fordon pris="129900"><name>Honda</name><modellTyp>1</modellTyp></fordon>
<fordon pris="119000"><name>Nissan</name><modellTyp>2</modellTyp></fordon>
```

But I want to get the numers ( 1 and 2) inside my modellTyp so the output should be
`<modellTyp1>` and `<modellTyp2>`

This is what my XSL file look like to output the result I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="ad">
<xsl:element name="fordon">
<xsl:attribute name="pris">
<xsl:copy-of select="price" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
<xsl:element name="modellTyp">
<xsl:value-of select="type" />
</xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe with an css stylesheet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically create the element name with curly braces in the [Attribute Value Template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates):

```
<xsl:element name="{concat('modellTyp', type)}">
    <xsl:value-of select="type"/>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: Of course!!
Used Concat earlier today but didn't remember It at this moment :)
Wont forget that now :)
Thanks.!

Comment: Simpler: `name="modellTyp{type}"> `

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Of course. Silly me. I think it's time to stop for the night :)

Comment: @lwburk: You said it first...   :)

Answer (score 1):

**@lwburk's answer is correct, but there is even a simpler/shorter solution**:

```
<xsl:element name="modellTyp{type}">     
  <xsl:value-of select="type"/> 
</xsl:element>
```